# Basics of real-time multiplayer game

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a simple multiplayer game. As I understand the main principle is to make  clients communicate ether directly to each other or to the server. Since I want some game data to be available online on my website, I'm inclined to create database that users will be connected to.

Is this valid? 
Is SQL/MySQL good idea to use in such scenario?
Would windows azure be any help?

Please help me. I really need some guidance here.

Comment: You may want to mosey on over to the game dev stack exchange gamedev.stackexchange.com. You should be able to get more help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store game data for use on a web site, you will definitely want to store it in some sort of database. Just so you know, SQL is a querying language for databases, MySQL is a DBMS (Database Management system) that you use SQL to "talk" to.

However, you certainly don't want to store ALL of your game interaction in a database, as database operations tend to take a long time (at least as far as a computer is concerned). Your server should have some sort of socket (probably TCP) that is talking to all the clients, passing messages and so forth.

The class reading from this socket would raise events or otherwise update the database for the information you want to be displayed on your website. Windows Azure would be a perfectly valid hosting platform for the website/server app, and so would pretty much any other web hosting solution. Some of the socket code could be easier going through Azure, so that may give it an advantage when choosing your host.

Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Comment: So should I make one of the clients as a "host" so that this so-called "host" would communicate with the rest of the clients and then use DB for just storing of the data? Thx in advance.

Comment: Making one of the clients a "Host" would be more of a peer-to-peer setup. Since said host would probably not have access to the central server database, I'm not sure how that would work. Your server probably has two components: the "game manager" and the "stats manager" the game manager routes messages, the stats manager deals with the database.

Comment: I have never developed server applications, so would you be able to help me with basics please? Am I required to rent server space in that case? Do I need to develop server application that all clients will be connecting to and then this application passes information to the server?

Comment: You would definitely need to rent server space. You would certainly have a server application, but I'm not sure what you mean when you say "pass information to the server" the server application *is* the server, and all clients connect to it. Does that make sense?

Comment: ok. Thank you very much. You are a great help!